Is it possible to control for autocorrelation within individuals and families using GLS corCAR1?
I have a sample of twins with repeated measures of BMI. I want to determine whether intake of a nutrient is associated with BMI trajectories. I have been using GLS in the nlme package in R. I have used correlation = corCAR1(form = ~age|twinID) but realise this doesn't account for autocorrelation in families (famID). Is it possible to control for both twinID and famID autocorrelation? I've tried correlation = corCAR1(form = ~age|twinID/famID) and correlation = corCAR1(form = ~age|famID/twinID) but this made no difference to the output.

If you don’t find a way to do that with GLS, you can do it with a Markov model that handles within-person correlation by adding lagged values as covariates but handles families using random intercepts.  See this for example.
